# Best practice for using React hooks and Context API to update global state and fetch/provide data from multiple endpoints

Tags: axios, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management, use-effect

I am new to React hooks/Context API. I have read the React hook/context docs, and I am still having trouble with the following:

1. My attempts to update global state by multiple consumer components
   currently causes frequent overwriting of context state due to
   rerendering (e.g., activity or details state is sometimes
   null/undefined). This probably is why...
2. ... I am getting 400 (bad request) and/or 500 (server) errors on random refreshes of the page (~30% of the time content loads as
   expected, ~70% errors are thrown. I believe this is happening
   because we have various context states that are being called
   asynchronously).
3. I am not sure how to implement Axios Cancellation, given that our `useEffect` hooks are calling dispatch functions (e.g.,
   `getActivities()`) in different files. The examples I've seen
   involve fetching data within the component (rather than in context).

**I am seeking assistance for #1 specifically. I would love guidance on how to accurately fetch data and store in context as global state, and then provide that context to child components, allowing them to consume/update context state without unnecessary rerendering.**

Tried to only provide relevant code snippets below:

**ActivityState.js -- should fetch activity data**

```js
...
const ActivityState = props => {
  const initialState = {
    activities: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false
  };

  const HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'user_id': 1
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ActivityReducer, initialState);
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

  const getActivities = async () => {
    const { loggedIn } = contactContext;
    let didCancel = false; // attempts to start implementing axios cancellation
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      dispatch({ type: GET_ACTIVITIES, payload: res.data.data.activities });
    } catch (err) {
      if (!didCancel) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' });
      }
    }
  }

  const updateActivity = (path, data) => { //update context state
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_ACTIVITY, payload: { path: path, data: data } });
  };

  const saveActivity = () => { //send new activity data to the backend
    const postData = {
      actions:  [{"293939": []}],
      activities: state.activities
    };
    try {
      const res = axios.post(url,{ data: postData }, { headers: HEADERS });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

return (
    <ActivityContext.Provider
      value={{
        activities: state.activities,
        data: state.data,
        backup_data: state.backup_data,
        getActivities,
        updateActivity,
        saveActivity,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ActivityContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ActivityState;
```

**ActivityReducer.js -- switch statements to be dispatched by ActivityState.js**

```js
...
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ACTIVITIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        activities: action.payload,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true
      };
    case UPDATE_ACTIVITY:
      const { payload: { path }, payload } = action;
      const data = state;
      if (!data.activities)
        return { data };
      const index = data.activities.findIndex(e => e.socium_tracking_number == path.id);
      if(index === -1)
        return { data };
      _.set(data, `activities[${index}].${path.field}`, payload.data);
      return {
        data,
      };
...
```

**DetailsState.js -- dispatch functions to fetch details**

```js
const DetailsState = props => {

    const initialState = {
        details: null,
    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(DetailsReducer, initialState);

    const getDetails = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            dispatch({ type: GET_DETAILS, payload: res.data.data[0].details});
        }catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    };

    return ( 
        <DetailsContext.Provider 
            value={{ details: state.details, getDetails }}
        >
            { props.children }
        </DetailsContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default SchemaState;
```

**DetailsReducer.js -- switch statement**

```js
export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DETAILS:
            return {
                ...state,
                details: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**ActivityTable.js -- component that consumes Activity Info**

```js
...
const ActivityTable = ({ activity }) => {
  const activityContext = useContext(ActivityContext);
  const { activities, filtered, getActivities } = activityContext;

  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState(activities.wait_time);

  // Get activity data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        await getActivities()
      }
      fetchData();
  }, []);
...
```

**CreateActivity.js -- component that consumes Activity and Details data**

```js
...
const CreateActivity = props => {
  const activityContext = useContext(ActivityContext);
  const { activities, filtered, getActivities, addActivity } = activityContext;

  const detailsContext = useContext(DetailsContext);
  const { details, getDetails } = detailsContext;

  // Get activity and details data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
     async function fetchData() {
       await getActivities();
       await getSchema();
     }
     fetchData();
  }, []);
...
```

I really tried to get smarter on these issues before approaching the SO community, so that my question(s) was more defined. But this is what I have. Happy to provide any info that I missed or clarify confusion. Thank you for your time